# C# httpwebrequest call returning SendFailure to URL yet the same URL call in Postman app works fine and works on another server fine

Tags: c#

I have this code in a windows service .exe C# I developed. It works and runs perfectly fine on 1 system that is windows 2019

```
try
{
      HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sforce_url);
      request.Headers.Add("X-LIVEAGENT-API-VERSION", @"40");
      request.ContentType = "application/json";
      request.UserAgent = "PostmanRuntime/7.24.1";
      request.Accept = "*/*";
      request.Headers.Set(HttpRequestHeader.CacheControl, "no-cache");
      request.Headers.Add("Postman-Token", @"d5abae19-e75c-4f30-884c-a04b4ed6a69b");
      request.KeepAlive = true;
      request.Headers.Set(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, @"X-Salesforce-CHAT=!uSRDMPsjpMolXkp5ExWNMAzwzvXh4d/K9CiKOdu3JgQbK2I3r3Q+Aa6EFA+NaWAzn19xRAoqzP3xMc4=");

      response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();         
}
catch (WebException e)
{
    if (e.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError) response = (HttpWebResponse)e.Response;
     else return false;
}
```

I have a new system/server that is windows 2019 where i have copied the same service .exe and hence runs this same code. I am not able to connect to my Sforce URL .

response is Null
e.Status is "SendFailure"
exception is "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send."
inner exception is "Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."

here is the puzzling part I can take the url i'm using and plug it in to Postman app for windows and it hits the url fine ! :(

then my old windows 2019 server again the service/C# code works fine and also POstman app on it of course works fine.

I'm not able to find any real differences between the servers and I doubt my IT dept is blocking anything OTHERWISE the same call from Postman would fail on the new server.

Any ideas why this is not working on the new windows 2019 server ?  I have tried to compare things such as the microsoft redistributables in add/remove programs and both are the same.  if it was something in the OS or the new server environment then the Postman call would fail.

UPDATE:
I ran Fiddler on the old and new system both are connecting or showing TSL 1.2, completely at a lose why this code works on the old win2019 server but not the new. here is fiddeler output of the url it the same on both servers while using Postman to connect.

```
A SSLv3-compatible ClientHello handshake was found. Fiddler extracted the parameters below.

Version: 3.3 (TLS/1.2)
Random: 21 32 C5 82 D2 EC 8C 6F B0 28 A6 6C D1 71 B9 95 ED C5 6C 21 32 F3 FF 3D 8F 49 77 56 AF A6 41 EC
"Time": 7/10/2039 9:45:05 PM
SessionID: 60 3E 39 30 E9 9B BB 2B 5D 82 AB 1D E3 15 BF 1F 3D 70 30 98 E2 78 5C 3F 81 C6 9C 5D E2 30 9F B3
Extensions: 
    server_name d.la3-c1-ia2.salesforceliveagent.com
```

Comment: These days, my bet is on TLS 1.2 being required and not enabled as default on your failing machine.

Comment: Did you try adding `System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;` before you make your calls?

Comment: i tried both of your suggestions, first adding the SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 before my response request code, then i enabled TLS 1.2 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/core/plan-design/security/enable-tls-1-2-server#bkmk_protocol .. then i tested with and without the SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 line, didn't make any differences. i was hoping setting the Tls12 reg entries from the msft link would resolve it. still scratching my head.

Comment: so on the server in Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Server , and in \Client TLS 1.2 is enabled. on the old server those settings don't exist, i disabled it on the new server and locked myself out of RDP now LOL :(. not sure how to get around this ? how can i just remove TLS 1.2 from the OS so it's like the other server i'm guessing that's my culprit i need to remove it some how.

Comment: i got it working see answer

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Filburt and @Andy, yesterday my brain was tired, got up this morning and started using Fiddler to test both servers. Fiddler would not see my C# HttpWebRequest on either server, researched and found i needed to add the following to my .exe.config file.

```
<system.net>
  <defaultProxy>
    <proxy bypassonlocal="False" usesystemdefault="True" proxyaddress="http://127.0.0.1:8888" />
  </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

Once i did Fiddler was capturing on the old server the requests. So i said GREAT! then I put the same code in place on the new server , ran Fiddler, start my app WHAMO it was working :) !! so apparently i needed this proxy setup on the new server. Yes the new server is in a totally different environment than the old server, it's all managed by my IT dept so definitely some differences in connections that need to be back.

BUT, this only works while Fiddler is running, I guess i'm going to have to figure out how to setup some proxy within this new windows 2019 server :( ?

So turns out this new server was using a Proxy server :) lol, i feel stupid now, so i just added that proxy to the .exe.config file for my C# app that fixed it